# How to create a case insensitive choice field from DRF normal choice field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to create a case insensitive choice filed such as `CaseInsensitiveChoiceField` that inherits and modifies `serializers.ChoiceField`

suppose I a creating a serializer as below

```
from rest_framework import serializers

my_field_choices = ["A", "BCD", "e"]

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_field = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=my_field_choices)
```

this serializer does not validate if I pass `data={"my_field": "a"}` or `data={"my_field": "BCd"}` or `{"my_field": "E"}` to it.

what I could do was

```
from rest_framework import serializers

my_field_choices = ["A", "BCD", "e"]

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    my_field = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[item.upper() for item in my_field_choices])
```

and then modify the data and then pass it to it:

```
data = request.body
data["my_field"] = data["my_field"].upper()
```

However, this is not very clean and I dont want to modify the request body because of validation. I am looking for a way to create a `CaseInsensitiveChoiceField` that tweaks `ChoiceField` and inherits from it. any idea how to do that?

also, I want the `MySerializer.data` return case `my_field`, irrespective of its data passed in being upper or lower case.

In summary, I want my serializer to accept upper or lower choices but return all lowercase data.

I dont clearly understand how these serializers and fields work. Otherwise, I may be able to do this.

This article can be helpful https://medium.com/@luccascorrea/django-rest-framework-creating-a-custom-serializer-field-de3e29846bc

Comment: I think you don't need a custom case insensitive field, but rather to override the save method, or implement a custom validator.